# Colorbox lightbox does not close with ESC when using iFrame with control that receives focus

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have a page that opens an lightbox using jQuery Colorbox. The lightbox opens an iFrame. The page in the iFrame is a form and it sets the focus to the first textbox in the form. With this, if I press ESC to close the lightbox, it does not work. If make the page to not set the focus to the textbox then ESC works, but if I click on the textbox the ESC does not work again. Is there a way to make the ESC to always work to close the lightbox even if other input fields or elements in the iFrame page have the focus?

Answer (score 0):

For this write code in the content page of the iframe

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){

    if(e.keyCode === 27)
    {
        parent.$.colorbox.close();
    }

});
```

It will work, I also having the same problem....but resolved.